# replace NAs in data frame with 'average if' of row

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, na

I have some data where each unique ID is a member of a group. There are some IDs with missing data, for these I'd like to take the average of the other members of the same group for that row.

For example, with the below data I'd like to replace the "NA" for id 3 in row V_2 with the average of the other Group A members for that row (average of 21 & 22). Similarly for id 7 in row V_3 it would be the average of 34 & 64.

```
Group=rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), each=3)
id=1:9
V_1 = t(c(10,20,30,40,10,10,20,35,65))
V_2 = t(c(21,22,"NA",42,12,12,22,32,63))
V_3 = t(c(24,24,34,44,14,14,"NA",34,64))

df <- as.data.frame(rbind(Group, id, V_1, V_2, V_3))
df

Group  A  A  A  B  B  B  C  C  C
id     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
X     10 20 30 40 10 10 20 35 65
X.1   21 22 NA 42 12 12 22 32 63
X.2   24 24 34 44 14 14 NA 34 64
```

Comment: Note that `"NA"` with quotes is a string with the two letters "N" and "A". A missing value `NA` has no quotes. When you put a string like "NA" in the middle of a `numeric` vector, it converts the whole column to `character` class instead, `class(c(1, "NA", 3))` is `character` but `class(c(1, NA, 3))` is `numeric`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using `dplyr`. The warnings occur because data frame columns are all character in your example (because the character class *Group* is in row 1). So ideally the whole data frame should be transposed...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tibble(data.frame(t(df))) %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(across(X:X.2, ~ as.numeric(.x))) %>% 
  mutate(across(X:X.2, ~ replace_na(.x, mean(.x, na.rm=T)))) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame()
        V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9
Group    A    A    A    B    B    B    C    C    C
id       1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
X       10   20   30   40   10   10   20   35   65
X.1   21.0 22.0 21.5 42.0 12.0 12.0 22.0 32.0 63.0
X.2     24   24   34   44   14   14   49   34   64
Warning messages:
1: Problem while computing `..1 = across(X:X.2, ~as.numeric(.x))`.
ℹ NAs introduced by coercion
ℹ The warning occurred in group 1: Group = "A". 
2: Problem while computing `..1 = across(X:X.2, ~as.numeric(.x))`.
ℹ NAs introduced by coercion
ℹ The warning occurred in group 3: Group = "C".
```

###### Same example using transposed data

```
df_t %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(across(X:X.2, ~ replace_na(.x, mean(.x, na.rm=T)))) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 9 × 5
  Group    id     X   X.1   X.2
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1    10  21      24
2 A         2    20  22      24
3 A         3    30  21.5    34
4 B         4    40  42      44
5 B         5    10  12      14
6 B         6    10  12      14
7 C         7    20  22      49
8 C         8    35  32      34
9 C         9    65  63      64
```

with transpose back to wider format

```
df_t %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(across(X:X.2, ~ replace_na(.x, mean(.x, na.rm=T)))) %>%
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame()
        V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9
Group    A    A    A    B    B    B    C    C    C
id       1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
X       10   20   30   40   10   10   20   35   65
X.1   21.0 22.0 21.5 42.0 12.0 12.0 22.0 32.0 63.0
X.2     24   24   34   44   14   14   49   34   64
```

##### transposed data

```
df_t <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C"), id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), X = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 
10, 10, 20, 35, 65), X.1 = c(21, 22, NA, 42, 12, 12, 22, 32, 
63), X.2 = c(24, 24, 34, 44, 14, 14, NA, 34, 64)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9"))
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked for me and is the solution i have gone with.

Answer (score 0):

Structuring the data the [tidy way](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) might make it easier. Package {Hmisc} offers a convenience `impute` helper (since this is such a frequent task). That way you could proceed as follows:

- tidy the data

```
## example dataframe df:
set.seed(4711)
df <- data.frame(Group = gl(3, 3, labels = LETTERS[1:3]),
                 id = 1:9,
                 V_1 = sample(c(NA, 1:8)),
                 V_2 = sample(c(NA, 1:8)),
                 V_3 = sample(c(NA, 1:8))
                 )
```

```
## > df |> head()
##   Group id V_1 V_2 V_3
## 1     A  1   1   7   6
## 2     A  2   4   8   2
## 3     A  3   3   2   3
## 4     B  4   6   4   1
## 5     B  5   5   3   8
## 6     B  6  NA  NA   4
```

- use {Hmisc} and {dplyr} together with the pipeline notation:

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)

df_imputed <- 
  df |>  mutate(across(V_1:V_3, impute, mean))
```

```
> df_imputed |> head()
  Group id V_1 V_2 V_3
1     A  1 1.0 7.0   6
2     A  2 4.0 8.0   2
3     A  3 3.0 2.0   3
4     B  4 6.0 4.0   1
5     B  5 5.0 3.0   8
6     B  6 4.5 4.5   4
```

Should you now prefer to replace missing values with groupwise medians instead of total means, the tidy arrangement (together with {dplyr}) requires only one additional `group_by` clause:

```
  df |> 
  group_by(Group) |>
  mutate(across(V_1:V_3, impute, median))
```